# tomcat base directory for logging

Tags: java, upstart, logging, tomcat

Not sure if this should be on StackOverflow..
I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install tomcat8 (with java8) on an ubuntu-12.04 instance. It uses the upstart script to install tomcat8 as as auto start service.

I'm using logback to do some logging in Tomcat. In the logback configuration I've configured a file appender like:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
  <file>myApp.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n  </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

When I start tomcat I see some logging in `var/log/upstart/tomcat.log` that it doesn't have permissions (as `tomcat`-user)to create myApp.log, but I'm confused where myApp.log is being written to.

For now I indicated the hard url in my logback configuration, so my problem is solved. However I'm still curious.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know your logger `ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender`, but you could use some variables to log into a desired folder, E.G.:

To log into root of your tomcat base folder:

```
${catalina.base}/logs/myApp.log
```

or in your user folder `/home/drjerry/`:

```
${user.dir}/logs/myApp.log
```

Comment: If you have a `logback.groovy`, use: `${System.getProperty('catalina.base')}`